# Direct connection to Internet without Proxy

Tags: java, networking, proxy

Is it possible to make a Direct connection to the Internet without using a Proxy.

Consider a case that my Organization has a Proxy and I use the DIRECT option given in the Java Proxy class.

```
SocketAddress addr = new
InetSocketAddress("webcache.mydomain.com", 8080);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.DIRECT, addr);
```

If you go by the documentation it states
**DIRECT which represents a direct connection, or absence of proxy.**

Which is exactly the way it behaves. When I use this option, I dont have to give any Proxy details and I can access the content from the Internet.

I have three questions

1. As per my understanding if an Organization has a Proxy, all network
   traffic should get routed through the Proxy. No one should be able
   to access the Network directly ?
2. I also noted that if I remove the Proxy details from IE, I can not
   access the Web :-( How can Java still do it ?
3. If in any Organization you can access both with the Proxy and
   Directly, how does the firewall block certain sites ? How does the
   firewall even work ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question 1 and 3 are a better fit for Serverfault.

Comment: All, some parts of this question might be suitable for Server fault but I am also interested in knowing how Java API is working. That part will never be answered at Server fault. I request you to keep this question at SO. Thanks.

Comment: Thats a community decision. But 2 out of 3 is the majority of questions ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all Network traffic goes through a Proxy, if your Organization has a Proxy. You can still go ahead and establish a Direct connection to the Internet. Mostly the Organizations will block Direct connections and force you to use Proxies. Some times they might allow you to have a Restricted Direct connection, which allows certain URL's and denies other ones.

Answer (score 4):

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.DIRECT, addr);
```

Is not the proper way to create a direct (no proxy) proxy directive. You should do

```
Proxy proxy = Proxy.NO_PROXY
```

The internal implementation of the Socket class and the HttpURLConnection checks if `proxy == Proxy.NO_PROXY` (note: "==", not "equals()"!).

It does NOT check if `proxy.getType() == Proxy.Type.DIRECT`.

Comment: thanks for the correction but how does the DIRECT type ignore the Organization proxy and establish a DIRECT connection with the external world. Why is a browser not able to do it.

Comment: new Proxy(Proxy.Type.DIRECT) is NOT a direct (no proxy). This may be a bug or oversight by the developers of Java, but there it is. Try your code with Proxy.NO_PROXY and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

2) You might have set the proxy in any system properties. If you are using any IDE, check the proxy setting of the IDE.